# How do you configure Makefile.am to put all objects in the current directory

Tags: compilation, automake

I am building pbs_mom for Torque. The latest autotools complain about subdir-ojbects option being disabled. I have enabled subdir-obects using AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE which allows me to get everything set up and configured. But when I do a make a conflict occurs because pbs_mom uses sources files for pbs_server but compiles them differently.

The pbs_mom_SOURCES line looks like the following

```
pbs_mom_SOURCES = catch_child.c mom_comm.c mom_inter.c mom_main.c       \
               mom_server.c prolog.c requests.c start_exec.c        \
               start_exec.h checkpoint.c tmsock_recov.c             \
               mom_req_quejob.c mom_job_func.c                      \
               mom_process_request.c alps_reservations.c            \
               release_reservation.c generate_alps_status.c         \
               ../server/attr_recov.c ../server/dis_read.c          \
               ../server/job_attr_def.c ../server/job_recov.c       \
               ../server/reply_send.c ../server/resc_def_all.c      \
               ../server/job_qs_upgrade.c
```

Before enabling subdir-ojbects the .o files from the ../server source files would be put in the current directory (src/resmom). But with subdir-objects enabled it keeps them in the same directory as the source which is src/server.

How can I direct the Makefile.am to move the .o files to the src/resmom directory?

Comment: Are those different `Makefile.am`s?  You can set the option on a per-file basis by putting `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects` in the `Makefile.am` instead of passing it to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` in `configure.ac` which will enable it globally.

Comment: They are different Makefile.am files. I tried that approach but it brings me back to the original error with the pbs_mom directory.